# How to default center everything on a page with Nikola and reStructuredText

Tags: restructuredtext, static-site

I'm using Nikola to generate a static site, which uses reStructuredText for writing contents. For one of the pages, I'd like to change the default alignment to center for everything on that page. Is there a simple option that I can specify to achieve this?